# how to find the post in the page is deleted or not in facebook Using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have some issue when i trying to find the post is deleted or active in the facebook page.

For example: if a user post a message in some facebook page(example:samsung). then the admin of the page is marked that post to hidden/delete.

when i hit the graph api with this post id, the api returns the data, but in the page that post is not visible. if the post is by the admin(page) its works fine. only if the post is by created by fans(others) and deleted by admin this issue happens..

https://graph.facebook.com/yyyyy_yyyyy?access_token=xxx (yyyyy_yyyyy is post id)

access_token have the read_stream and read_insights permission

Any body know how to fix this...

Thanks...

Comment: Yes, you don't have permissions to have access to this post. Because, the post made by admin will be accessible to all users, but if  someone posted on a page, and admin set the post to hidden/deleted then you can't have access to it, but admin has via his/her access_token. or if you somehow have the page token with you then you may have the access to every post on the page.

Comment: @RenoJones : but i was able to get the hidden/deleted post when i use the post_id. actually that post is hidden/deleted. so api shouldn't return that. the issue is still the is post not deleted by the fan. only i want to know the fans post hidden/deleted status. is there a way to find this?